# External monitor loses signal from MacBook Pro after returning from sleep

Tags: sleep, macbook

I'm a new MacBook Pro user. I have it connected to a non-Retina external monitor using a USB-C dongle. After being idle several minutes, it goes to sleep. Then, when I wake up the notebook with my touch ID, the external monitor doesn't receive a signal. If I go to the Apple menu and System Preferences, it doesn't show up under Display. Only when I unplug the dongle and plug it back it will it show up and then the monitor will start displaying again. How do I fix this problem so that the monitor will be detected right away when the MacBook resumes from sleep? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually the display at fault, failing to wake fast enough for the system to recognise it is still present.
It's basically a no-fix situation at consumer-level.

Usually, the only workaround is if you can force the screen to wake before the computer does - pressing any hardware button on the front is the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

Was using an old Dell U2417H, facing same issue until I change the monitor "Sleep" into "Never" in the monitor's display setting menu.